# How to determine the generic type from protocol implementation

Tags: ios, swift

I have a protocol that has a function that can return a `String` or a `[String: String]`. This is my declaration:

```
protocol Test {
  associatedtype T: Hashable
  func returnSomething() -> T
}
```

Then I want a default implementation for `returnSomething`, so I made a protocol extension:

```
extension Test {
    func returnSomething() -> T {
         let valueToReturn = readValueFromPLISTthatCanReturnAStringOrDictionary() as T
        return valueToReturn
    }
}
```

So finally I have 2 clases, `TestString` and `TestDictionary` that both implements `Test` protocol and I want to indicate the `T` parameter and I want to use the default implementation. How I do this?

```
class TestString: Test {}

class TestDictionary: Test { }

class TestString: Test where Test.T = String or similar?
```

Comment: Your problem is quite abstract, and I don't quite understand it. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: The default implementation is always used if you don't override it, so I'm not sure what the issue is

Comment: I want to use the default implementation, but i can't use it because TestString and TestDictionary don't tell the Test Protocol which generic type is T.

Comment: The idea behind this is to make returnSomething return a String when the implementer class is TestString and a dictionary when the implementer is TestDictionary

Comment: So i'm guessing you have many classes that you want to have one of these two default implementations, and you want to pick which one based on the type you set T to?

Comment: Yes that's correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a protocol that has a function that can return a String or a [String: String]. This is my declaration:

No problem. Let's write that down.

```
enum StringOrDictionary {
    case string(String)
    case dictionary([String: String])
}

protocol Test {
    func returnSomething() -> StringOrDictionary
}
```

> Then I want a default implementation for returnSomething, so I made a protocol extension:

Sounds good. I'll assume that `readValueFromPLISTthatCanReturnAStringOrDictionary()` actually returns `Any`, since that's what is returned by `propertyList(from:)`.

```
extension Test {
    func returnSomething() -> StringOrDictionary {
        let value = readValueFromPLISTthatCanReturnAStringOrDictionary()

        switch value {
        case let string as String: return .string(string)
        case let dictionary as [String: String]: return .dictionary(dictionary)
        default: fatalError() // Or perhaps you'd like to do something else
        }
    }
}
```

It'd probably be nice to name your type something more meaningful than `StringOrDictionary`, but other than that, it should be pretty straightforward. Just make a type that means what you say. You want a type that means "OR" and that is an enum. (If you want a type that means "AND" that's a struct BTW.)

---

Regarding your answer, this isn't legal:

```
class RandomClass: Test where Test.T == String {
    func getValue() {
        let bah = doSomething() // I don't need here to specify bah's type.
    }
}
```

The way to define your `T` is to implement the required method.

```
class RandomClass: Test {
    func returnSomething() -> String {
        return ""
    }
}
```

If you wanted to share some common code, then you can attach that as an extension rather than a default implementation. You could write a `returnString()` method and call it from the RandomClass.returnSomething(). This is all very useful in some cases, but I definitely wouldn't use it in this case. You don't mean "returns any possible type (T)." You mean "returns one of two possible types" and that's an enum, not a generic.

Update: Apparently they've added a new feature that they've talked about but I thought wasn't in yet. You could now implement `RandomClass` this way:

```
class RandomClass: Test {
    typealias T = String
}
```

(Which is a very nice new feature, even if it's not a good answer for this problem.)

Comment: that looks nice! Seems clear to me. Anyway, can you have a look at my answer?

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov Yep; in other languages this feature is even called a "tagged union." It's much more powerful than C's untagged union (which is very dangerous)

Comment: Yeah, when I use unions in C, I'm essentially obligated to make an enumeration (the "tag") to keep track of the union's "case", and a struct to package together the tag and the union. How tedious!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution to your immediate problem:

Create 2 subtypes of your protocol, each with a different definition of the associated type, and a different default implementation. You select which default implementation you'd like your classes to use by picking between the 2 sub types.

The next issue here is that `[String: String]` isn't `Hashable`. This is due to a lack of support for conditional conformances (e.g. the ability to express that a `Dictionary` is `Hashable` iff the keys and values are both `Hashable`), one of Swift's largest downfalls, IMO. You'll probably want to use the type erasing wrapper `AnyHashable`.

```
protocol ResultProvider {
  associatedtype Result: Hashable
  func getResult() -> Result
}

protocol StringResultProvider: ResultProvider {
    typealias Result = String
}

extension StringResultProvider {
    func getResult() -> String {
        return "A string result"
    }
}

protocol IntResultProvider: ResultProvider {
    typealias Result = Int
}

extension IntResultProvider {
    func getResult() -> Int {
        return 123
    }
}

class TestIntResult: IntResultProvider {}
class TestString: StringResultProvider {}

print(TestString().getResult())
print(TestIntResult().getResult())


// protocol DictionaryResultProvider: ResultProvider {
//     typealias Result = [String: String]
// }

// extension DictionaryResultProvider {
//     func getResult() -> [String: String] {
//         return ["A dictionary": "result"]
//     }
// }

// class TestDictionaryProvider: DictionaryResultProvider {}
```

Comment: Does circumventing the problem using `Any` and forced casts count as a solution?

Comment: It was a bad example returning any, i updated my answer to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the typealias when you extend the class, like so:

```
protocol Test {
    associatedtype T: Hashable
    func returnSomething() -> T
}

extension String: Test {
    typealias T = Int
}

func def() -> Int {
    return 6
}

extension Test {
    func returnSomething() -> T {
        return def() as! Self.T
    }
}

"".returnSomething()
```

> 6

However, I couldn't find a way to do it without force casting.

Comment: Thats not what i ask for. Basically i want a class to implement that protocol and have the ability to use the returnSomethingFunction. But to do that, i need to tell the class which type is gonna use. If i moved the generic parameter to the function all work ask expected, so func testSomething<T>() -> T and then the function knows what to return when i do let aDict: [String: String] = ATestDictionary.returnSomething()

Answer (score 0):

The only working solution is made the generic in the function and specify the variable type when calling the function. I was wondering if i could specify the T type when i implement the protocol in the class, similar like this:

```
class RandomClass: Test where Test.T == String {
    func getValue() {
        let bah = doSomething() // I don't need here to specify bah's type.
    }
}
```

But previous example just don't work, so an alternative could be this:

```
protocol Test {
    func doSomething<T>() -> T
}

extension Test {
    func doSomething<T>(key: String) -> T {
        return returnDictOrStringFromPLIST(key: key) as! T
    }
}

class TestString: Test {
    func getValue() {
        let bah: String = doSomething()

    }
}

class TestDict: Test {
    func getValue() {
        let bah: [String: String] = doSomething()

    }
}
```